# Pandas to_sql in django

Tags: django, pandas

I am trying to use Django's db connection variable to insert a pandas dataframe to Postgres database. The code I use is

```
df.to_sql('forecast',connection,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

And I get the following error

> Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': relation "sqlite_master" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?...

I think this happens because the Django connection object is not an sqlalchemy object and therefor Pandas assumes I am using sqlite. Is there any way to use .to_sql other than make another connection to the database?

Comment: What is you connection string?

Comment: `django.db.connection` would have worked, auto-selecting the default connection setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to create db configuration in setting.py file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db('DATABASE_URL_DEFAULT'),
    'other': env.db('DATABASE_URL_OTHER')
}
DB_URI_DEFAULT=env.str('DATABASE_URL_DEFAULT')
DB_URI_OTHER=env.str('DATABASE_URL_OTHER')
```

If you want to create sql_alchemy connection you should use DB_URI_DEFAULT or DB_URI_OTHER

in the **init** method of the class you will use .to_sql method you should write

```
from you_project_app import settings
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

class Example:

 def __init__(self):
        self.conn_default = create_engine(settings.DB_URI_DEFAULT).connect()
```

And when you use .to_sql method of pandas it should be like this:

```
df_insert.to_sql(table, if_exists='append',index=False,con=self.conn_default)
```

Comment: Reference for how to convert django database settings into sqlalchemy connection strings: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html